# Changing environmental variable in command prompt only works for current command prompt?

Tags: cmd, environment-variables

Suppose I run a cmd with admin and execute the following command.(Sorry if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find the answer anywhere)

```
>set SOME_ENV_VAR=some_path_1
>echo %SOME_ENV_VAR%
some_path1
```

And suppose the initial value of SOME_ENV_VAR was some_path_0
But when I open another command prompt and write

```
>echo %SOME_ENV_VAR%
```

The output is

```
some_path_0
```

So I'd like to know, why the value of SOME_ENV_VAR doesn't change in system, and how to change the value of SOME_ENV_VAR in cmd globally?

Comment: Use the command `SETX /?` to read about how to set an environment variable permanently.

Comment: As @KJ noted, using `SETX` will not change the environment variable in the current command shell. `SETX` save the value in the location referenced when a new command shell starts (registry). Using `SET` in the current command shell is still needed. It would be too easy if there were a command line switch on `SETX` such as `/C` to indicate that it should change the current set as well.